# Frictional torque on a unifrom rotating Square plate

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

So I wanted to ask if we have a square plate rotating with an angular velocity of w initially about an axis perp to the table through its center on the table such that normal and friction act on the surface uniformly, how do we find the torque due to friction. Like if we had a rotating body with a base area of circular cross section ,it would have been pretty easy taking the differential element circular but here we cannot do that unfortunately .So how do we take the differential element.

Comment: Google something like [equation of a square in polar coordinates](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=equation+of+a+square+in+polar+coordinates) for lots of links as this is really a Mathematics question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any shape can be made up from elements of size $dx \times dy$ at the position $x, y$.

[image: Element]

The mass of the element is $dm = \sigma\,dx\,dy$, where $\sigma$ is the area density, so the normal force is $\sigma\,g\,dx\,dy$ and the frictional force is:

$$ dF = \mu\,\sigma\,g\,dx\,dy $$

The radial distance is $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ so the torque due to the frictional force as the object rotates is:

$$ d\tau = \mu\,\sigma\,g\,\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}dx\,dy $$

And to get the total torque you just integrate $d\tau$. For an arbitrary shape this is going to be complicated, but for a square of side $2a$ this gives us:

$$ \tau = \mu\,\sigma\,g \int_{-a}^{+a} \int_{-a}^{+a} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}dx\,dy $$